# Cached route does not reflect route table

Tags: linux, caching, ip, routes

### Linux Ip route cache

On my Ubuntu 12.04 box I have a static route for a public IP address so that it goes to a NAT box. It works as specified and continued to work fine, except recently the route will stop going to the NAT box and start going through the default gateway (the IP is reachable through both).

The route table has not changed and it still reflects the static route however looking at the cached entry it is displaying the default route as it 'next hop'. Running #ip route flush cache clears the cache and it starts routing correctly. Eventually the cache will start referring to the default gateway and I need to flush again.

Any ideas on why this might be happening? I was thinking the NAT box at some point becomes un-contactable and then the default route becomes a better option and hence it starts using that. However I see no point when the boxes become un-contactable (no interface issues) and they are part of the same subnet. Happy to supply further information or outputs if not enough information supplied.

Answer (score 0):

We are having the same issue here at work and would love to know if you have found a solution to this PIMA.

We were unable to route to some hosts on one subnet so we did:

```
IP route delete 192.0.0.0/22 via 172.1.1.1
```

and then a:

```
Ip route add 192.0.0.0/22 via 172.1.1.1
```

We also found by just removing old routes fixed the issue. So it looks like any updates to the routing table refreshes or renews the the table.

I do not believe this is a good fix or one that should be used long term, but it works in a pinch. Has anyone seen a better way or a long term fix?